# Maven not copying all resource files

Tags: maven

For some reason Maven is ignoring any extension that isn't .properties, .xml, or .bat. Can someone please help me understand how to fix this? It's a project that was created by another developer, and I have limited knowledge of Maven. I tried searching for a solution, but so far nothing helped.
The following is how my resources folder is configured in the POM.xml

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>../</targetPath>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.bat</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
                <include>*.sh</include>
                <include>*.txt</include>
                <include>*.sql</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

*.sh, *.txt, and *.sql  is something I added, and these are the files that I have in my resources folder
[image]

After clicking "update maven project", my target directory only shows log4j.properties, test.xml, and test3.bat. How do I get maven to copy the other extensions, too?

Complete POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>greenfund</groupId>
<artifactId>adminconsole</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2</version>
<name>admin-console</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>greenfund</groupId>
        <artifactId>greenfund-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.54</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>greenfund.adminconsole.MainWindow</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>../lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>./</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>../</targetPath>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.bat</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
                <include>*.sh</include>
                <include>*.txt</include>
                <include>*.sql</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you define `<targetPath>../</targetPath>`. and also `<directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>` ? The first one is simply wrong... the second is default... furthermore why have you set so many includes? Furthermore to help you have to post your full pom file..because we don't know what it's inside your pom file???

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, I updated the post with the complete POM.xml file. I wasn't sure on the specifics of targetPath, or the defaults, but it seemed to pick up .properties, .xml, and .bat files correctly, so I didn't mess with that setting. I removed the <directory> tag, and changed targetPath to ./ but that didn't help solve the issue.

Comment: Why do you use `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>` ? The targetPath is simply wrong as I mentioned... remove that configuration also remove those includes etc. also why defining  source/target to java 10? Why using the maven-dependency-plugin and copying to a lib directory ? The version of the maven-compiler-plugin is very old... ? Based on the configuration for maven-jar-plugin you are trying to build an executable jar? But that jar will not being executabled because it's needed it's dependencies etc. Best would be having example project on github or alike...